# Django timesince function is wrong

Tags: python, django

I want to create a function that returns the list of last points per vehicle that have sent navigation data in the last 48 hours. I create a view it works and it displays name correctly but I want to show that How long has it been since the data was sent.
I use timesince but it shows wrong. It adds 13 hours and prints same hours for all data. I think it is related to my models because I cannot do anything about hours, minutes.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipPHZ.png)

How can I fix it?

**navigation.html**

```
          <td>{{ result.datetime|timesince }}</td>
```

**models.py**

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    plate = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.plate)


class NavigationRecord(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vehicle)
```

**views.py**

```
def get_48_hours(request):

    time_48 = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=48)
    results = NavigationRecord.objects.filter(datetime__gte=time_48).order_by('-datetime')
    context = {

            'results': results,
    }
    return render(request, 'navigation.html', context)
```

**Note:** Any advice is accepted for improving my code.

Comment: In which time zone are you located?

Comment: I am in Turkey and in my settings : TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is most likely caused because you are comparing a [naive datetime object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) to an object with associated time zone information from your database.

This is a common source of bugs. To prevent this, *never* use `datetime.now()` in your Django code, and instead use the Django utility function `timezone.now()`. Here's your code rewritten to use the `timezone.now()`:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def get_48_hours(request):

    time_48 = timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=48)
    results = NavigationRecord.objects.filter(datetime__gte=time_48).order_by('-datetime')
    context = {

            'results': results,
    }
    return render(request, 'navigation.html', context)
```

Comment: I fixed this but there is no change

Comment: It works very well